# Simple Linear Regression of an Exponential Function

Tags: exponential-function, least-squares, linear-regression

I have that $$z = φexp(−γx)$$

The question states: By taking an appropriate transformation of the experimental response, fit a simple
linear regression model and provide estimates of φ and γ.

I have done the following:
$$log(z) = log(φ) - γx$$
$$log(z) = β0 + β1xi$$

So, $$β0 = log(φ)$$ and $$β1 = -γ$$

Is it as simple as working out the value of β0 and then taking the expontential of it to get φ, and working out the value of β1 and sticking a minus sign in front of it to get γ?

Then if I were to do a confidence interval for φ and γ would I use the new numbers I've worked out, or would I work out the confidence interval β0 and β1 and then do the same transformations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is that simple. If your original measurements are $(x_1, z_1), (x_2,z_2), \ldots, (x_n, z_n)$, you can fit a simple linear regression model to $(x_1, \log z_1), (x_2, \log z_2),\ldots, (x_n,\log z_n)$. You then rearrange the coefficients of your linear regression to read off estimates for your original parameters $\gamma$ and $\phi$, as you've done.

Comment: So if I were to work out a confidence interval, should I use β0 and β1 and use the same transformations? Or should I now use γ and ϕ?

Comment: @Vicky Assuming linear regression is a legitimate model for the $(x_i,\log z_i)$, you can work out confidence intervals for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$. Then applying the transformations $\phi = \exp(\beta_0)$ and $\gamma = -\beta_1$ to the endpoints of these will get you valid confidence intervals for the parameters $\gamma$ and $\phi$.